# Android: how to store variable values to registry?

Tags: android, variables, registry

I am creating an application which requires login and enables user to configure some settings.

However I would like to enable user to store preferred settings, username and password.

Does anyone know how to store and retrieve values from registry?
Another possibility is using SQL Lite database but if possible I would prefer to store values to registry.

Thanks!

Comment: Android is a linux environment. There is no such thing as the registry on Android :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"Preferences is a lightweight mechanism to store and retrieve key-value pairs of primitive data types"
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html